# How to check if string is a word or a bunch of letters without meaning?

Tags: python

Consider the following function

```
def gen_wrd():
    res = '' 
    for i in range(random.randrange(2,10)):
        res += randomchoice(string.ascii_lettes)
    return res
```

It returns a string, if you run this function for a long time you will get some words that have a meaning (book, cat, library, Ivan, James, ..., etc  )

Now the goal is to check if the string generated has a meaning or is a valid word used by human beings and not a bunch of letters grouped together

Comment: Find a Python library that provides dictionaries in the languages you'd like to support.

Comment: You can use a 3rd party library like [PyDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

There is no definite answer to your question. A word might be a word in one language and not a word in another language because there is nothing special about the combinations of sounds that make up words. Therefore, there is no algorithm that we can apply that separates words from non-words.

**Longer Answer:**

Having said that, there are models that can be created that try and calculate a prediction about whether a combination of letters is a word or not. For example, words consisting of consonants and vowels and ending in "ing" are very likely to be English words. Much more than a nonsense word like "gyzl".

Using a model that uses character-level bigrams, you can create language-specific probabilistic model that can tell you, for example, what the probabilities are that a word belongs to a particular language. You may be able to determine a baseline probability that you use as a threshold so that everything above the threshold you consider to be a word, and everything below the threshold is "not a word".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a spell-checker library. For example: [pyenchant](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/)

Answer (score 0):

Use PyDictionary module and check it there exists meaning for that word.

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

word='good'
dict = PyDictionary()

meaning = dict.meaning(word)

if meaning !=None:
   print("Valid Word")   
   print(meaning)
else:
    print("Not a Valid Word")
```